# Create function that checks if ID is unique

Tags: function, plsql

I want to make a function that checks if ID that i will insert is unique. 
This is what i did:

```
-- the function has to return true if ID is unique and false if ID is allready used(not unique)

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check_uniqueID
    ( p_ID IN STORE."ID"%TYPE)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
    AS 
      v_IsUnique BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE STORE
      ADD CONSTRAINT check_unique_id UNIQUE (p_ID);
      -- how can i programm that he returns true if its unique and false if its not?
      v_IsUnique := TRUE;
      RETURN v_IsUnique;
    END;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is what i have right now  

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check_uniqueID
( p_ID IN STORE."ID"%TYPE)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS 
  v_ID STORE."ID"%TYPE;
  v_IsUnique BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  SELECT "ID"
  INTO v_ID
  FROM STORE
  WHERE "ID"=p_ID;
  
  IF v_ID = NULL THEN
  v_IsUnique := true;
  ELSE 
  v_IsUnique := FALSE;
  END IF;
  
  RETURN v_IsUnique;
END;

Comment: Why? You should have a unique index, with automatically generated values, that forces it to be unique.

Answer (score 3):

The only good practice here is to use unique constraint and sequence. Add constraint (you need to do it once):

```
ALTER TABLE STORE ADD CONSTRAINT check_unique_id UNIQUE (p_ID);
```

Create sequence for IDs (once):

```
create sequence my_sequence;
```

Use it in `INSERT` statements:

```
insert into STORE (id, another_field) 
values (my_sequence.nextval, 'some value for another field');
```

or:

```
insert into STORE (id, another_field) 
select my_sequence.nextval, one_more_field
  from some_table;
```

If you don't want to use a sequence, you need to process exception `ORA-00001`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `ALTER TABLE` in a function just to check if a constraint is being violated is really bad practice. You should have the constraint on the table permanently, and handle the `ORA-00001: unique constraint (constraint_name) violated` exception should it be thrown. You also seem to have misunderstood the syntax of `ALTER TABLE` since you're trying to add a constraint on the nonexistant column of `STORE.p_ID`.

However, if you must use a function to reproduce functionality that the database provides via check constraints (for pre-validation in the UI or similar), this would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_uniqueid (p_id IN NUMBER)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
   li_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT   COUNT(1)
   INTO     li_count
   FROM     store s
   WHERE    s.id = p_id;

   RETURN li_count = 0;
END;
```

Comment: But this would still be horrible and error-prone if used concurrently. If two processes insert the same ID, the function will give both an OK, since they only see their changes after COMMIT. This is why a constraint is THE ONLY right way to do this!

Comment: Agreed, and ultimately it sounds like a design flaw anyway, a column called "id" on a table should probably be populated via a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT query to check whether the value already is stored in the table.